# SQL Adding a flag based on one column that has multiple values

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to add a flag in the table based one column that includes multiple values. For example..

```
Student_id |       Exam_type   
   123             Practice  
   123          Recertification
   123            Certification
   456             Practice
   456            Certification  
   789          Recertification
   135             Practice
   246             Practice
   246            Certification
```

I want to be able to flag which of the students have taken practice exams.
The output needs to be:

```
Student_id | Practice_taken
123              Y
456              Y
789              N
135              Y
246              Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and a `case` expression:

```
select student_id,
       (case when sum(exam_type = 'Practice' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as practice_taken
from t
group by student_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with row_number()

```
select student_id, case when max(rn)=1 then 'Y' else 'N' end as Practice_taken from
(select student_id,row_number() over(partition by student_id order by case when exam_type = 'Practice' then 1 else 0 end desc) as rn
from t) where rn=1
group by student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use `exists` :

```
select student_id, (case when exists (select 1 
                                      from table t1 
                                      where t1.student_id = t.student_id and
                                            t1.Exam_type = 'Practice'
                                     ) 
                         then 'Y' else 'N' 
                    end) as practice_taken
from table t
group by student_id;
```